# Extracting ways from node to node using Overpass QL

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api, overpass-turbo

Is there a way to extract ways (basically I need path from node to node in overpass)

For example:

```
node(1270323047)->.c;
(.c;<;>;)->.d;
way.d;
```

would recursively find all relations that node 1270323047 belongs to and then extract all ways.

Now my questions is, is there a way to iterate trough all ways and have start and stop conditions for example begin at `node(id1)` and stop at `node(id2)` (assuming ways are linked to previous, next)?

I wonder if this is possible at all. Because there is no link between nodes <-> ways.

**UPDATE:** For example if I have relation: https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/7916536#map=11/47.2771/8.5530&layers=T,
how can I extract only from Wiedikon - Zurich HB path (from node (train_stop) - to node (train_stop)

Then I want to do this generally from any to train stops, I want a path that connects the 2.

So far I used OSRM(Open Source Routing Machine), but there are some issues if I don't pinpoint exact location of train stations so I have some crazy 180deg turns. (even if I set penalty on lua profile.)

Comment: I read your question 3 times now, and still don't understand what you're trying to do. What do you mean by "iterate through all ways and have start and stop conditions?".

Comment: @mmd I updated an answer, does that clarify somewhat?